# Replace first character in $args

Tags: nginx

I would like to replace the first character of `$args` in `rewrite`

I have the following:

```
return 302 https://domain/accounts/registration?_uid=1928&_tag=$request_uri&$args;
```

if `$args` are empty I just get a link that ends with a `&` which is not a big problem but if I have some `$args` I get `something&?arg1` which is wrong since `&?` is considered as a continuation of the previous parameter.

How can I remove the first letter ( `?` ) from `$args` ?

Answer (score 0):

`$request_uri` already includes the optional `?` and the query string. So your extra `?` is coming from `$request_uri` and not from `$args`.

You could try using `$uri&$args` instead of `$request_uri` which will replace the embedded `?` with a `&`.

For example:

```
return 302 https://domain/accounts/registration?_uid=1928&_tag=$uri&$args;
```

However, any percent-encoded characters in `$request_uri` are fully decoded by the time that `$uri` is constructed - which may or may not impact your application.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_uri) for more.